# CompleteWith directive in spray routing

Tags: scala, akka, spray

Hi i would like to use completeWith to use actor per request pattern in my test scala project, but i cannot get reference to this directive from spray. I tried using complete directive, and think that somewhere is magnet which will respond in manner that i want, but this:

```
pathPrefix("search") {
  path("book" / "getAvailable") {
    get {
      respondWithMediaType(`application/json`) {
        complete(instanceOf[Seq[Book]]) { completeFunction =>
```

Don't work. Do you know what directive in spray works like completeWith in Akka?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is there is no completeWith in spray, i used akka http, since spray is no longer developed:

```
      completeWith(instanceOf[Seq[BookApp]]) { completeFunction =>
        system.actorOf(Props(new HandlerActor(bookService, authorService))) ! Handler.AllBooks(completeFunction)
      }
```